# Change font color on the basis of a background image

Tags: javascript, html, colors, background

On iPhone, for example, the color of the icon labels changes from white to black if white is not readable on the phone wallpaper. 
Well, I'd like to reproduce it in Javascript, if possibile.

I have this HTML:

```
<div style="background-image: url(http://just5.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/OneRepublic-Counting-Stars.jpg)">
    <span style="color: white;">Counting Stars</span>
</div>
```

As you can see on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2WQJA/) "Counting Stars" is not readable, so I'd like to change the color of the text. I'm using [color-thief.js](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/) to get the dominant color of an image, but how to use it with a background-image?

Comment: Well, using that plugin, you only have to pass your image to the plugin, so, you should get the uri from the background property. Anyway, if you know which images are going to be used, you can populate an object with the image uri and the color to use

Comment: The problem is that I don't know which images are going to be used...

Comment: As I said, using that plugin, you only have to pass your image src to the plugin. This means, for each image (with class "x"), call to the plugin and get response to apply to closest "y" element. Or something like :) I forget that you can invert the color obtained from the plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you can get the color from the image, there are images where neither black nor white would be readable.

I suggest that you put a faint shadow around the text, that makes it readable even when the background is white, and it doesn't affect the background much when it's dark. Example:

```
text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0 0 2px;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2WQJA/1/

You can experiment with different opacity (the `0.5` in the example) and radius (the `2px` in the example).

Answer (score 0):

i dont think any such method is possible, well anyhow you can do one thing, you can put the images in an array and they assign the font-color value to it with a loop.